# TypeORM PostgreSQL statement timeout

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm looking for help with TypeORM and PostgreSQL. To avoid long running queries, I would like to set a statement timeout at the connection level.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Connection config that's working for me:

```js
{
    name: "default",
    // .....
    extra: {
        application_name: "your_app_name",
        statement_timeout: 30000 // 30s
    }
}
```

We can check how these extra options are used in the driver:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/68a5c230776f6ad4e3ee7adea5ad4ecdce033c7e/src/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver.ts#L1361

Available options are listed here: https://node-postgres.com/api/pool

And here: https://node-postgres.com/api/client

> The config passed to the pool is also passed to every client instance within the pool when the pool creates that client.

Answer (score 3):

[TypeORM documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-options.md#common-connection-options)

> `maxQueryExecutionTime` If query execution time exceed this given max
> execution time (in milliseconds) then logger will log this query.

If that doesn't do what you want you can use `extra` to send postgres driver configuration.

> `extra` - Extra connection options to be passed to the underlying
> driver. Use it if you want to pass extra settings to underlying
> database driver.

Comment: According to the documentation it will only log to the console. Does it also abort the query?

maxQueryExecutionTime - If query execution time exceed this given max execution time (in milliseconds) then logger will log this query.

Comment: You "said set a statement timeout" which was a bit vague...  That's true for `maxQueryExecutionTime` which is why I also pointed out `extra` and you can send more postgres specifc params through that.  https://node-postgres.com/api/client

Comment: Indeed you did mention `extra`. Thank you very much for your time Jim, I'll take a look further. I already upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL you can pass query_timeout option directly to pg driver through extra.

```
{
   type: 'postgres',
   ...
   extra: {
       query_timeout: 2500
   }
}
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5429#issuecomment-939919873