# Error: read ETIMEDOUT while running PostgreSQL migrations in GitHub Actions pipeline

Tags: github-actions

Migrations are using typeorm for execution. Locally it works fine, it runs in a 1-2mins.
The issue appears when I'm running the same script in pipeline.
It takes about 5-7mins to run migration step and after this period of time throws ETIMEDOUT.

Credentials are correct, because sometimes execution was successful (very rare case):

[image]

Most of time it runs without any success:

[image]

I had an idea that it can be related to database queries timeout, so I increased statement_timeout in parameter group in AWS RDS to max value. Now it runs longer but anyway fails after 20mins(this time is random):

[image]

I have no idea how it can fail after 20mins of run while on local env it runs a few mins. More confusing thing is that sometimes it works fine, but it's rare case. It seems to me that network of GitHub Actions is very unstable or slow causing this issue.
I've already set up AWS Code Build and it works good there.

It would be great if someone can help to find the solution. It seems that I faced up with something really specific.

```yaml
name: Staging migrations pipeline
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging

env:
  NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
  NPM_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.NPM_EMAIL }}
  POSTGRES_HOST: staging-db.xxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
  POSTGRES_USER: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_STAGE_USER }}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_STAGE_PASSWORD }}
  POSTGRES_DATABASE: sync-db

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Clone repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install packages
        run: npm install
      
      - name: Run migration
        run: npm run migration:run

      - name: Building the project
        run: npm run build

      - name: Update version
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "${NPM_EMAIL}"
          git config --global user.name "cicd"
          npm version patch -m "[skip ci]-new version" --force
      - name: Push tags
        run: git push origin && git push origin --tags

      - name: Publish vesion
        run: npm publish
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666571/typeorm-postgresql-statement-timeout. Looks like you may try configuring `query_timeout` as well.